# Font awsome icons not showing within jade templates

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug, font-awesome

I'm using jade for templating within my node.js/express app. but when i try to using font awesome the icons don't show, only list bullets. I've tried all methods i've found by search engine. such as fa.fa-globe issue.
here's is the code taken from the footer.jade

```html
 span This is some other footer stuff.
    ul
      li.fa.fa-google-plus
        a(href='#')
        i.fa.fa-facebook
      li
        a(href='#')
        i.fa.fa-lg.fa-twitter
      li
        a(href='#')
        i.fa.fa-lg.fa-google-plus
      li
        a(href='#') 
        span.fa.fa-lg.fa-linkedin
 span and some more footer stuff.
```

As you can see above there are various methods i've tried, i, span and classes

And my layout.jade is as follows:

```html
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet', media='screen')
    link(href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  include ./header.jade
  body(style="padding-bottom:10rem;")
    block content

  script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js')
  script(src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is that you're missing the `rel='stylesheet'` attribute for the font-awesome `<link>`. That will get the font-awesome icons working.

However if you're trying to get the icons to replace the bullets in the list, you'll need to tweak your footer's list items as [shown](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#list) on the font-awesome examples page. For example:

```html
span Hello world
  ul.fa-ul
    li
      i.fa-li.fa.fa-facebook
      a(href='#') Facebook
    li
      i.fa-li.fa.fa-lg.fa-twitter
      a(href='#') Twitter
    li
      i.fa-li.fa.fa-lg.fa-google-plus
      a(href='#') Google+
    li
      i.fa-li.fa.fa-lg.fa-linkedin
      a(href='#') LinkedIn
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant. its now showing them as vertical list, is there any quick fix to get them horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing an empty symbol where the icon should be, you may need to add encoding to your layout head:

```
meta(charset="utf-8")
```